# Running script with `Lein run`and `Clojure -M` hang. Works in REPL

Tags: shell, clojure, echo

```
$ lein --version
Leiningen 2.9.10 on Java 17.0.4.1 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
$ clojure -version
Clojure CLI version 1.11.1.1155
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.4.1" 2022-08-12
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.4.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.4.1+1, mixed mode)
```

I have some *very* basic code I'm trying to run.

```
(use '[clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])
(defn -main [] (sh "echo" "Hello, World!"))
(-main)
```

In a REPL, this predictably returns

```
{:exit 0, :out "Hello, World!\n", :err ""}
```

However, when that is the contents of a script (verbatim), `clojure -M` just hangs. Uncommenting the `ns` and trying to run this as a project with `lein run` produces the same behavior.

I've also tried with `requires` + `:refer` and putting that in with the namespace. I've tried explicitly printing stdout with `(print (:out (sh "echo" "stuff")))`.

My project.clj:

```
(defproject findbad "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.11.1"]]
  :source-paths ["."]
  :repl-options {:init-ns findbad}
  :main findbad)
```

and .lein/profile.clj:

```
{:user {:plugins [
                  [lein-try "0.4.3"]
                  [flat-layout/lein-template "1.6.0"]
                  [simple-layout/lein-template "0.1.0"]]}}
```

I can get the following to run with `clojure -M`, but `lein run -main` now throws errors (an improvement?).

```
(ns findbad
  (:gen-class))

(use '[clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])

(defn -main [] (print "Hello, World"))

(-main)
```

```
{:clojure.main/message
 "Execution error (ArityException) at user/eval140 (form-init17641850740462455309.clj:1).\nWrong number of args (1) passed to: findbad/-main\n",
 :clojure.main/triage
 {:clojure.error/class clojure.lang.ArityException,
  :clojure.error/line 1,
  :clojure.error/cause
  "Wrong number of args (1) passed to: findbad/-main",
  :clojure.error/symbol user/eval140,
  :clojure.error/source "form-init17641850740462455309.clj",
  :clojure.error/phase :execution},
 :clojure.main/trace
 {:via
  [{:type clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException,
    :message
    "Syntax error macroexpanding at (/tmp/form-init17641850740462455309.clj:1:74).",
    :data
    {:clojure.error/phase :execution,
     :clojure.error/line 1,
     :clojure.error/column 74,
     :clojure.error/source "/tmp/form-init17641850740462455309.clj"},
    :at [clojure.lang.Compiler load "Compiler.java" 7665]}
   {:type clojure.lang.ArityException,
    :message "Wrong number of args (1) passed to: findbad/-main",
    :at [clojure.lang.AFn throwArity "AFn.java" 429]}],
  :trace
  [[clojure.lang.AFn throwArity "AFn.java" 429]
   [clojure.lang.AFn invoke "AFn.java" 32]
   [clojure.lang.Var invoke "Var.java" 384]
   [user$eval140 invokeStatic "form-init17641850740462455309.clj" 1]
   [user$eval140 invoke "form-init17641850740462455309.clj" 1]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7194]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7184]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler load "Compiler.java" 7653]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler loadFile "Compiler.java" 7591]
   [clojure.main$load_script invokeStatic "main.clj" 475]
   [clojure.main$init_opt invokeStatic "main.clj" 477]
   [clojure.main$init_opt invoke "main.clj" 477]
   [clojure.main$initialize invokeStatic "main.clj" 508]
   [clojure.main$null_opt invokeStatic "main.clj" 542]
   [clojure.main$null_opt invoke "main.clj" 539]
   [clojure.main$main invokeStatic "main.clj" 664]
   [clojure.main$main doInvoke "main.clj" 616]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 137]
   [clojure.lang.Var applyTo "Var.java" 705]
   [clojure.main main "main.java" 40]],
  :cause "Wrong number of args (1) passed to: findbad/-main",
  :phase :execution}}
```

How am I getting a "wrong number of args"? I'm passing nothing to a function that takes nothing.

Even if I could get that `(print "Hello, World")` example to work, that's not what I'm interested in.

edit: Okay, I'm not sure what I did differently, but I can get it to work with `(print (:out (sh "echo" "stuff")))`. Also, the hanging was fixed with `(shutdown-agents)`.

Comment: Do you want to make this work with clj-cli or lein - or both? If you want `lein`, why not start with e.g. `lein new app findbad`, which basically gives you a sane start.  Why do you call `(-main)`? The point for main is yo be called from the build tool or later via the jar, if you build one.  Top-level `use/require/...` in a `ns` is discouraged - use `:require` inside the `ns`.

Comment: I did start this with `lein new`. I call main because without it the script did nothing when I ran it (I did that first). And I tried :require in with ns, but that didn't work. At all.

Comment: Note the difference between `lein new x` and `lein new app x` - the later bootstraps something else

Comment: I see you're point, however I get the same behavior.

Comment: You do `lein new app x && cd x && lein run` and get an error (don't see "Hello World") printed?

Comment: The actually problem was me being an idiot and passing "-main" as an argument. Unless you count the differing behavior between `clojure -M` and `lein run` (the former needs `(-main)` for output and the latter spits errors if I include `(shutdown-agent)`), any further discussion is against Stack's comment policy. However if you're willing to chat about it, I have *a lot* of issues with lein. I love the language, but hate the build system. I'd hate to move on to another language just because of it.

Comment: I'd guess you are not battling against the build tool, but against clojure basics. Top-level side-effects are no-no, because they run at compile time). Put all your code in functions, call the relevant code from the `-main` function and "call" it from outside where you see fit. If you have further problem, feel free to add a new question to show your different problem.

Comment: What you are seeing is my take on a MWE. Coming from Julia, I very much have the mindset of putting everything in functions. In the actual code, I have a dedicated function to shelling out. It's the build system. Something about it and me do not mix. Sometimes that happens, like me and Python. Supposedly easy, but even after three semesters using it, I could not get it to work for me. What's more, my issues have so far been exclusive to Leiningen. `clojure -M` and `bb` are perfectly happy with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main function accepts no arguments (`[]`). Clojure invokes `-main` from cli with list of command line arguments causing arity exception. Try adding `& args` to `-main` arguments vector:

```
(defn -main [& args] (print "Hello, World"))
```

Comment: Oh, I see. How silly of me. I'm trying to pass "-main" as a CLI argument aren't I? Adding the `& args` makes it happy to eat my input. Alternatively I could simply not try passing anything. Thanks.

Comment: You can also print `args` from `-main` function and try `lein run` or `clojure -M` with and without arguments to see what goes to `args`.

`(defn -main [& args] (pr args))`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. I'm not trying to print the arguments. The actual script is meant to gather some info, process it, and then print that.